# How do you say "graveside" and "gravestone" in Latin?

Tags: word-request

I am trying to translate the lyrics of the [Eric Bogle's song The Green Fields of France](https://youtu.be/iYCxeY8wTLU) to Latin. The first two verses are:

> Well, how do you do, young William McBride?
> Do you mind if I sit here by your **graveside**?

I'd translate this as:

> Ergo, quid agis, o iuvenis William McBride?
> Licetne per te mihi sedere apud tuum **sepulchrum**?

Is there a better way to translate the word "graveside" than "sepulchrum"?

Then it goes:

> I'll rest for a while beneath the warm summer sun,
> I've been walking all day and I'm nearly done.
> I see by your **gravestone**, you were only nineteen...

I'd translate that as:

> Requiescam breviter infra calidum solem aestatis,
> ambulabam per totam diem, et paene finio.
> Video tuo **monumento** te habuisse solummodo undeviginti annos...

Is there a better word than "monumentum" for "gravestone"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Medieval *Stabat Mater* has these lines:

> Stabat mater dolorosa
> **iuxta crucem** lacrimosa
> dum pendebat filius

Which is translated as:

> His sorrowful mother was standing
> **next to the cross**, full of tears,
> While her son was hanging there.

I'd say graveside is pretty much "right next to the grave [physically]", so with that, I'd recommend ***iuxta sepulchrum*** as a good translation of "graveside."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with cmw that *juxta sepulcrum* is what you want for "at the graveside".

I also think that *monumentum* is a fine word for "gravestone". You could use *cippus* as an alternative if you are looking for something different. I'm not sure it would be better or worse, but it would be different.